# base64 data URL to blob and then write file ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, base64

i have converted canvas to data url.

```
 var dataUrl = this._CANVAS.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.7);
```

how to convert dataURL to blob and then save it as a image file in app folder ionic.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly save your dataUrl(base64 image) to your gallery no need to convert it to blog with this ionic native [base64 to gallery](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64-to-gallery/) plugin, it saves your base64 encoded image to gallery

Get your DataUrl without passing type to it just use

```
var dataUrl = this._CANVAS.toDataURL()
```

after you get your dataURL :

```
this.base64ToGallery.base64ToGallery(dataUrl, { prefix: '_img' }) // pass your variable dataUrl and it will save it to your storage.
```

one more important thing after installing the plugin check if it saves the image to your gallery because most of the times it won't(on android device as i used android can't say the same about ios devices) because you may not have your WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions set, so for that i had to use one more plugin [android permissions](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/) which checked the required permissions and then i was able to save the image to gallery

Comment: i added this given permission. Now it is showing "Image Could not be decoded" ERROR

Comment: Don't pass Mime type just use var dataUrl = this._CANVAS.toDataURL() // don't pass anything inside

Comment: Or try passing ('image/png') instead of jpeg.

Comment: Thanks mahesh.. it downloaded to galary ..thanks alot

Comment: Now if it did help you can you please mark it correct someone else will also benifit from it if they see it as correct answer

Comment: Can we get image name and file location just after saving to galary??

Comment: i am having less then 15  reputation so cant mark it

Comment: You dont need 15 reputation for marking your own question correct.. You just can't upvote accepting an answer doesn't need reputation

Comment: Ok Got it, Accepted . So now my question is Can we get image name and file location just after saving to galary??

Comment: can you tell me why do you need it for showing it to user or you want to perform some other action.

Comment: in my app i show my user a alert after the image is saved and asks them if they want to view their image and if yes i open the image

Comment: I want to perform another action.. copy that Canvas file to specific location in app folder ... I want to do same to display images and open image.

Comment: sorry sahil right now i cannot help because i need to personally check the response what we are getting after saving the image before suggesting you and as i am away from my laptop its not possible today. i will surely get back to you tomorrow if you are unable to find any solution